# DocuSign API to fech AuditLogs Information

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a DocuSign eSignature Admin API to fetch the [AuditLogs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=vit1583277397519.html&_LANG=enus) information

I want to get events about Admin-related activities like changes to account settings, billing information, plan type, users, etc

This is the URI that gets called from the UI...is there a public API for the same?

`/accounts/<account_Id>/audit_logs`

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answers to your questions. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

The Monitor product provides that information programmatically. See https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/

Ask your DocuSign contacts for access